# Xbox 360 controller not detected Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: games, xbox-360, lsusb

When I USB plug my new xbox 360 controller, it is not dectected by the system. The `lsusb` command does not show the controller:

```
us 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:0408 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 046d:082c Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I fix this? Does that mean that the controller itself is broken (it's second-hand)? The command `lsmod | grep xpad` show:

```
xpad                   36864  0
ff_memless             16384  1 xpad
```

Thanks!

[EDIT]

Following  suggestion, I entered j`ournalctl --follow` and plugged my controller:

```
juil. 12 14:56:58 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 28 using xhci_hcd
juil. 12 14:56:58 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
juil. 12 14:56:59 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
juil. 12 14:56:59 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
juil. 12 14:56:59 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
juil. 12 14:56:59 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
juil. 12 14:56:59 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb usb3-port2: attempt power cycle
juil. 12 14:57:00 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 30 using xhci_hcd
juil. 12 14:57:00 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
juil. 12 14:57:00 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
juil. 12 14:57:00 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: device not accepting address 30, error -71
juil. 12 14:57:01 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
juil. 12 14:57:01 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
juil. 12 14:57:01 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
juil. 12 14:57:01 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb 3-2: device not accepting address 31, error -71
juil. 12 14:57:01 juju-W35-37ET kernel: usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: Watch `journalctl --follow` as you plug in your xbox 360 controller.

Comment: I copy-pasted the output in my question. Oddly, I got this output on USB 3 port but no output at all on USB 2 port...

Comment: isn't there something about wireless controllers don't send their data over the charger? aka the cable is only for power charging. the wireless data needs a wireless receiver to function